# ASP.Net Core Web API - ResponseCache attribute is not adding "Cache-Control" header to the reponse

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, cache-control, asp.net-core-webapi, responsecache

I have multiple controllers in my ASP .NET Core application and I am using ReponseCache attribute like this on a few methods:

```html
//controller 
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("CorsPolicy")]
public class InsightsApiController : Controller

//method    
[Route("CoursesTextContent")]
[HttpGet]
[DecryptFilter]
[ResponseCache(Duration = 60)]
public IActionResult GetCoursesContent(string locale, string tabKey, string widgetType)
```

The issue that I am having is that for one controller this is working fine and I can see the response in chrome dev tools with "Cache-Control:public max-age=60" but in a different controller when I add this attribute its adding "Cache-Control:no-cache". I compared both controllers and methods in them and they are configured same. I have also tried to add ASP.NET Core middleware recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware) but same results. I am calling both methods from Angular2 webpage. Is there something I can do from the client side (request)? or something in the ASP.NET Core app setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a session middleware enabled in the startup.cs file of my ASNETCore webapi project. I removed it and its working for all calls/controllers now. Not sure why it was causing problem only with one Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a trailing parenthesis

```
 [ResponseCache(Duration = 60]
```

needs to be

```
 [ResponseCache(Duration = 60)]
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo in the question but I actually have it in the code.

Comment: No worries.  It's pretty odd that you could be using the same ResponseCache attribute on two different action methods in different controllers and getting different results.  Perhaps you have a action filter or middleware that is overriding the `Cache-Control` header and setting it to `no-cache`.

Comment: Originally I was not using any middleware but then I tried adding it in there from the link that I have in my question and that did not help either. I have tried all different options (public, private, Vary...) but same result. It is strange.

Comment: Maybe try reproducing the behavior in a trivial web project that only has two trivial controllers, each with one method.  Then add in complexity to more closely match your actual project until you find the issue.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about it. Will do that now. Thank you for quick feedback. I appreciate it.